# How to skip over NA's when calculating time difference in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a data frame with an ID column, a date column, and a column with specific dates that the ID was treated. The ID is not treated on every single date, so there are NA's in the treatment date column when the ID was not treated. What I want to do is create a new column, with the number of days passing since the previous treatment date.

```
#sample data
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("82002","82002","82002","82002","82002","82002","82002",
                         "82002","82002","82002","82002","82002"),
                  MtDate = c("2019-07-17","2019-07-17","2019-07-18","2019-07-18","2019-07-18",
                             "2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-21",
                             "2019-07-21","2019-07-22","2019-07-23"),
                  TrtDate = c("2019-07-17","NA","2019-07-21", "NA", "NA",
                              "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA","NA", "NA", "2019-07-23"))
#format MtDate and TrtDate columns as dates
df1$MtDate = ymd(df1$MtDate)
df1$TrtDate = ymd(df1$TrtDate)
```

I have tried using mutate, and subtracting the current treatment date from the previous treatment date, which works for rows where the TrtDate is not NA

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
arrange(TrtDate) %>%
mutate(DaysSincePrevTreat = TrtDate - lag(TrtDate, default = first(TrtDate)))%>%
data.frame()
```

Giving me this result

```
> df1
       MtDate    TrtDate DaysSincePrevTreat
1  2019-07-17 2019-07-17             0 days
2  2019-07-18 2019-07-21             4 days
3  2019-07-23 2019-07-23             2 days
4  2019-07-17       <NA>            NA days
5  2019-07-18       <NA>            NA days
6  2019-07-18       <NA>            NA days
7  2019-07-19       <NA>            NA days
8  2019-07-19       <NA>            NA days
9  2019-07-19       <NA>            NA days
10 2019-07-21       <NA>            NA days
11 2019-07-21       <NA>            NA days
12 2019-07-22       <NA>            NA days
```

But what I don't want to 'ignore' the dates when TrtDate = NA, and have the number of days since the previous treatment date in the DaysSincePrevTreat column for each MtDate.... Below is my desired result

```
> Desired.Result
      ID     MtDate    TrtDate DaysSincePrevTreat
1  82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17                  0
2  82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17                  0
3  82002 2019-07-18         NA                  1
4  82002 2019-07-18         NA                  1
5  82002 2019-07-18         NA                  1
6  82002 2019-07-19         NA                  2
7  82002 2019-07-19         NA                  2
8  82002 2019-07-19         NA                  2
9  82002 2019-07-21 2019-07-21                  0
10 82002 2019-07-21 2019-07-21                  0
11 82002 2019-07-22         NA                  1
12 82002 2019-07-23 2019-07-23                  0
```

I could do this manually, but my actual data includes 100,000+ points and 200+ different treatment dates.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Seems you are better off removing the `NA`s altogether?

Comment: I need to keep the NA's because in the actual data, there are other columns associated with rows that have NA's in the TrtDate that are important. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `tidyr::fill` (documented [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html)) to fill the NA values of TrtDate forward in your data.frame. This will allow you to effectively "skip" NA values when calculating the quantities of interest in your data.frame. I would do this type of activity on a copy of your original data field, so that you can visually spot-check the logic and recover the `NA` values if necessary.

Some code to do this (plus some of your data-cleaning/normalization):

```r
df1 %>% 
     # convert to dates
     dplyr::mutate(TrtDate = lubridate::ymd(dplyr::na_if(TrtDate, "NA")),
                   MtDate = lubridate::ymd(dplyr::na_if(MtDate, "NA"))) %>%
     dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
     # sort by MtDate
     dplyr::arrange(MtDate) %>%
     # create a copy of TrtDate which we will use for filling
     dplyr::mutate(FillTrtDate = TrtDate) %>% 
     # fill forward 
     tidyr::fill(FillTrtDate, .direction = 'down') %>% 
     # compute difference
     dplyr::mutate(PrevTrtDate = lag(FillTrtDate, default = first(TrtDate), order_by = MtDate),
         DaysSincePrevTreat = MtDate - PrevTrtDate) %>%  
     dplyr::ungroup()
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   ID    MtDate     TrtDate    FillTrtDate PrevTrtDate DaysSincePrevTreat
   <fct> <date>     <date>     <date>      <date>      <drtn>            
 1 82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17 2019-07-17  2019-07-17   0 days           
 2 82002 2019-07-17 NA         2019-07-17  2019-07-17   0 days           
 3 82002 2019-07-18 2019-07-21 2019-07-21  2019-07-17   1 days           
 4 82002 2019-07-18 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21  -3 days           
 5 82002 2019-07-18 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21  -3 days           
 6 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21  -2 days           
 7 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21  -2 days           
 8 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21  -2 days           
 9 82002 2019-07-21 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21   0 days           
10 82002 2019-07-21 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21   0 days           
11 82002 2019-07-22 NA         2019-07-21  2019-07-21   1 days           
12 82002 2019-07-23 2019-07-23 2019-07-23  2019-07-21   2 days
```

What this structure makes clear is that there are some inconsistencies in your original example data & the desired output. But these are issues that the tools above should help you resolve.

## edit: details on "inconsistencies"

The provided data frame was:

```r
> df1
      ID     MtDate    TrtDate
1  82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17
2  82002 2019-07-17         NA
3  82002 2019-07-18 2019-07-21
4  82002 2019-07-18         NA
5  82002 2019-07-18         NA
6  82002 2019-07-19         NA
7  82002 2019-07-19         NA
8  82002 2019-07-19         NA
9  82002 2019-07-21         NA
10 82002 2019-07-21         NA
11 82002 2019-07-22         NA
12 82002 2019-07-23 2019-07-23
```

It looks like, from your desired output, there is a typo on the 3rd record. Correcting this yields:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("82002","82002","82002","82002","82002","82002","82002",
                         "82002","82002","82002","82002","82002"),
                  MtDate = c("2019-07-17","2019-07-17","2019-07-18","2019-07-18","2019-07-18",
                             "2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-21",
                             "2019-07-21","2019-07-22","2019-07-23"),
                  TrtDate = c("2019-07-17","NA","2019-07-18", "NA", "NA",
                              "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA","NA", "NA", "2019-07-23"))
```

or

```r
> df2
      ID     MtDate    TrtDate
1  82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17
2  82002 2019-07-17         NA
3  82002 2019-07-18 2019-07-18
4  82002 2019-07-18         NA
5  82002 2019-07-18         NA
6  82002 2019-07-19         NA
7  82002 2019-07-19         NA
8  82002 2019-07-19         NA
9  82002 2019-07-21         NA
10 82002 2019-07-21         NA
11 82002 2019-07-22         NA
12 82002 2019-07-23 2019-07-23
```

To get the desired output, I would fill forward as above, but omit the `lag` step:

```r
df2 %>% 
    # convert to dates
    dplyr::mutate(TrtDate = lubridate::ymd(dplyr::na_if(TrtDate, "NA")),
                  MtDate = lubridate::ymd(dplyr::na_if(MtDate, "NA"))) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
    # sort by MtDate
    dplyr::arrange(MtDate) %>%
    # create a copy of TrtDate which we will use for filling
    dplyr::mutate(FillTrtDate = TrtDate) %>% 
    # fill forward 
    tidyr::fill(FillTrtDate, .direction = 'down') %>% 
    # compute difference, while converting to dates
    dplyr::mutate(DaysSincePrevTreat = MtDate - FillTrtDate) %>%  
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

or

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   ID    MtDate     TrtDate    FillTrtDate DaysSincePrevTreat
   <fct> <date>     <date>     <date>      <drtn>            
 1 82002 2019-07-17 2019-07-17 2019-07-17  0 days            
 2 82002 2019-07-17 NA         2019-07-17  0 days            
 3 82002 2019-07-18 2019-07-18 2019-07-18  0 days            
 4 82002 2019-07-18 NA         2019-07-18  0 days            
 5 82002 2019-07-18 NA         2019-07-18  0 days            
 6 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-18  1 days            
 7 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-18  1 days            
 8 82002 2019-07-19 NA         2019-07-18  1 days            
 9 82002 2019-07-21 NA         2019-07-18  3 days            
10 82002 2019-07-21 NA         2019-07-18  3 days            
11 82002 2019-07-22 NA         2019-07-18  4 days            
12 82002 2019-07-23 2019-07-23 2019-07-23  0 days
```

You can then `select(-FillTrtDate)` to remove that helper-column if you like.

Comment: Thank you jackinovik and hello_friend! Yes, I did have a typo in my sample data. Thanks for catching this and the code works. Much appreciated.

Comment: @j.wes519 You are very welcome. Happy this was helpful to you!